# Networking home computers without permission

Tags: network-monitoring

My husband is divorcing me. We have three computers using the same router. I think he has recently setup a home network without my permission. He has now locked his computer with passwords. I am starting to have problems with my computer and have found files which state that I do not have permission to open. At times my computer shut down be itself and lockup frequently. I believe he is remotely accessing my computer.What can I do to block access to my computer. He denies that the computers are networked. I brought a IPad but I think he has obtained the IP Address. I am wondering if he now can access my IPad. 
Please tell me what I can do.
Thanks TORRIE

Comment: whats is the operating system of your pc ?

Comment: Your husband is not accessing your computer remotely. Your computer locking and shutting down is a hardware issue.  You cannot access a computer just by knowing the "ip address" real life does NOT work like the movies.

Answer (score 5):

Take the harddrive out, Copy the data, Format the drive, Reinstall from scratch and secure the system properly. Keep old data around as an external source in case you need anything off it.

Or more likely in this case, take it to a shop and get them to do the above.

Also, the IP address is not sensitive data, you should have security measures in place to prevent access (firewalls, bios passwords, file permissions, login permissions etc etc). Think of the IP address like your postcode or house number. You still have a front door and a lock, right ?